# Adding up variables

Tags: vb.net, variables

I have written a program to calculate the weight of coins in a money bag and if there is too much weight for the coins that should be in there it will tell me how many coins to remove. For example a Bag of 1p coins should have 100 coins in it to total £1. A 1p coin weighs 3.56 grams so a bag of 100 should weigh 356 grams. The program will allow the user to enter the weight and money type and tell them exactly how many coins to add or remove to be on the exact weight.

What I need to do now is have a running total of the number of coins that have been added and the number of coins that have been taken away. This is where I am struggling. I am trying to make this as simple as possible to teach students.

This is what I have so far:

I have a form with a text box called `WeightEnteredtxt` to enter the weight in the bag. I have a text box called `CoinType` to enter the coin type.

I then have labels to display what the bag should weigh (`ShouldWeigh`), how many grams over the bag is (`OverBy`), the word "add" or "remove" depending on if the amount over is positive or negative (`posneg`) and the number of coins to remove or add (`numdiff`).

```
Dim b1ps As Integer = 356 ' this is the weight of a bag of 1p's
Dim b2ps As Integer = 356 'this is the weight of a bad of 2p's
Dim b5ps As Integer = 325 'this is the weight of a bag of 5p's
Dim b10ps As Integer = 325 'this is the weight of a bag of 10p's
Dim b20ps As Integer = 250 'this is the weight of a bag of 20p's
Dim b50ps As Integer = 160 'this is the weight of a bag of 50p's
Dim b1pounds As Integer = 190 'this is the weight of a bag of £1's
Dim b2pounds As Integer = 120 'this is the weight of a bag of £2's

Dim GramsDifferent As Double 'this is a variable ready to use with working the difference in weight.
Dim WeightEntered As Double = WeightEnteredtxt.Text 'this is to store the weight entered.
Dim RemoveOrAdd As Double 'this is to store the number of coins to be taken out or added.

Dim removed As Integer = 0

If CoinType.Text = "1" Then
    ShouldWeigh.Text = b1ps
    GramsDifferent = 356 - WeightEntered
    OverBy.Text = GramsDifferent
    RemoveOrAdd = GramsDifferent / 3.56
    numdiff.Text = Math.Round(RemoveOrAdd, 0)
End If
If CoinType.Text = "2" Then
    ShouldWeigh.Text = b2ps
    GramsDifferent = 356 - WeightEntered
    OverBy.Text = GramsDifferent
    RemoveOrAdd = GramsDifferent / 7.12
    numdiff.Text = Math.Round(RemoveOrAdd, 0)
End If
If CoinType.Text = "5" Then
    ShouldWeigh.Text = b5ps
    GramsDifferent = 325 - WeightEntered
    OverBy.Text = GramsDifferent
    RemoveOrAdd = GramsDifferent / 3.25
    numdiff.Text = Math.Round(RemoveOrAdd, 0)
End If
If CoinType.Text = "10" Then
    ShouldWeigh.Text = b10ps
    GramsDifferent = 325 - WeightEntered
    OverBy.Text = GramsDifferent
    RemoveOrAdd = GramsDifferent / 6.5
    numdiff.Text = Math.Round(RemoveOrAdd, 0)
End If
If CoinType.Text = "20" Then
    ShouldWeigh.Text = b2ps
    GramsDifferent = 250 - WeightEntered
    OverBy.Text = GramsDifferent
    RemoveOrAdd = GramsDifferent / 5.0
    numdiff.Text = Math.Round(RemoveOrAdd, 0)
End If
If CoinType.Text = "50" Then
    ShouldWeigh.Text = b2ps
    GramsDifferent = 160 - WeightEntered
    OverBy.Text = GramsDifferent
    RemoveOrAdd = GramsDifferent / 8.0
    numdiff.Text = Math.Round(RemoveOrAdd, 0)
End If
If CoinType.Text = "£1" Then
    ShouldWeigh.Text = b2ps
    GramsDifferent = 190 - WeightEntered
    OverBy.Text = GramsDifferent
    RemoveOrAdd = GramsDifferent / 9.5
    numdiff.Text = Math.Round(RemoveOrAdd, 0)
End If
If CoinType.Text = "£2" Then
    ShouldWeigh.Text = b2ps
    GramsDifferent = 120 - WeightEntered
    OverBy.Text = GramsDifferent
    RemoveOrAdd = GramsDifferent / 12.0
    numdiff.Text = Math.Round(RemoveOrAdd, 0)
End If
Dim added As Integer = 0
If Val(numdiff.Text) > 0 Then
    posneg.Text = "Add"
    added = added + Val(numdiff.Text)
    TAdded.Text = added
End If
If numdiff.Text < 0 Then
    posneg.Text = "Remove"
End If

NumBagsChecked.Text = Val(NumBagsChecked.Text) + 1
```

Comment: Create two class members `amountAdded` and `amountRemoved` on your form and add/subtract their values in your calculation algorithm

Comment: If you take a standard plastic coin bag (of the sort that you put coins into to pay into the bank)  you'll see that they are designed to take £20 in £1 or £2 pound coins, £10 in 50p or 20p coins, £5 in 10p or 5p coins and finally £1 in 2p or 1p coins.  Consequently there is something seriously awry with your weights as defined at the start.   Similarly you define RemoveOrAdd as a Double.  It should be an Integer given that you can't add or subtract bits of coin.  Do you actually know what the correct weight of each bag of coins is?  Your basic facts need to be correct first.

Comment: Yes i know what the correct weights are. 1p=3.56@100 per bag total 356. 2p=7.12@50 per bag =356, 5p=3.25@100 per bag =325,10p=6.50@50 per bag=325, 20p=5.00@50 per bag=250, 50p=8.00 @20per bag=160, £1=9.50@20 per bag=190 and £2=12.00@10per bag =120.

Answer (score 0):

Right then, try this

Take a simple windows Form and add to it a text box called txtTotalWeight.
Also add a comboBox, don't bother naming it.

in the code behind the default Form1 add the following:

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private myCoins As New List(Of Coin)
    Private BagWeights As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
    Private CoinWeights As New Dictionary(Of String, Double)
    Private CoinsInBag As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Private ActualNumberOfCoinsInBag As Integer

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
        Dim TotalWeight As Double
        Dim txt As String = cb.Text
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotalWeight.Text) Then
            TotalWeight = CDbl(txtTotalWeight.Text)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You Must enter a weight of Coins")
                    Exit Sub  'no point in continuing if there is no weight
        End If


        If ValidateWeightAdded(TotalWeight, CoinWeights.Item(cb.Text)) Then

            Dim CorrectNumber As Integer = CoinsInBag.Item(cb.Text)
            Dim AddRemove As Integer = CorrectNumber - ActualNumberOfCoinsInBag
            MessageBox.Show(AddRemove.ToString)

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You have added an incorrect weight or some of your coins are fakes")

        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SetupCoinsList()

        For Each c In myCoins
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(c.Name)
            CoinWeights.Add(c.Name, c.WeightOfCoinInGrammes)
            CoinsInBag.Add(c.Name, c.NumberAllowedInCoinBag)
            BagWeights.Add(c.Name, c.WeightOfCoinInGrammes * c.NumberAllowedInCoinBag)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub SetupCoinsList()
        Dim onePenny As New Coin With {.Name = "OnePenny", .NumberAllowedInCoinBag = 100, .WeightOfCoinInGrammes = 3.56}
        Dim twoPenny As New Coin With {.Name = "TwoPence", .NumberAllowedInCoinBag = 50, .WeightOfCoinInGrammes = 7.12}
        Dim fivePenny As New Coin With {.Name = "FivePence", .NumberAllowedInCoinBag = 100, .WeightOfCoinInGrammes = 3.25}
        Dim tenPenny As New Coin With {.Name = "TenPence", .NumberAllowedInCoinBag = 50, .WeightOfCoinInGrammes = 6.5}
        Dim twentyPenny As New Coin With {.Name = "TwentyPence", .NumberAllowedInCoinBag = 50, .WeightOfCoinInGrammes = 5.0}
        Dim fiftyPenny As New Coin With {.Name = "FiftyPence", .NumberAllowedInCoinBag = 20, .WeightOfCoinInGrammes = 8.0}
        Dim onePound As New Coin With {.Name = "OnePound", .NumberAllowedInCoinBag = 20, .WeightOfCoinInGrammes = 9.5}
        Dim twoPound As New Coin With {.Name = "TwoPound", .NumberAllowedInCoinBag = 10, .WeightOfCoinInGrammes = 12.0}
        myCoins.Add(onePenny)
        myCoins.Add(twoPenny)
        myCoins.Add(fivePenny)
        myCoins.Add(tenPenny)
        myCoins.Add(twentyPenny)
        myCoins.Add(fiftyPenny)
        myCoins.Add(onePound)
        myCoins.Add(twoPound)
    End Sub

    Private Function ValidateWeightAdded(ByVal totalCoinWeight As Double, ByVal coinWeight As Double) As Boolean
'Essentially this just determines if the total weight of the coins is exactly divisible by the weight of the selected coin type.
        Dim myResult As Double = totalCoinWeight / coinWeight
        If myResult = (Fix(myResult)) Then
            ActualNumberOfCoinsInBag = CInt(myResult)
        End If
        Return myResult = (Fix(myResult))
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Coin

    Property Name As String

    Property NumberAllowedInCoinBag As Integer

    Property WeightOfCoinInGrammes As Double



    Public Sub New()
    End Sub


End Class
```

There are much more efficient ways of doing all this but it should give you a starter and a pointer towards using some other rather useful constructs (like dictionaries).

The bulk of the code is concerned with setting up the key information that you need about the coins themselves.  All we actually need is something to call them, what they weigh and how many go in a bag.  That's what the coin class does.

Then we need a way to quickly access the correct information about each coin.  Dictionaries are really useful for this sort of thing.

The form load event just sets all this up.

Then all you need to do is add a weight and then select the coin type (much better to have a selection you control than have the added grief of verifying that what was entered is correct).

When you select a coin type you need to verify that you have a weight, and crucially that that weight is exactly divisible by the weight of the coin type you chose.

If it is exactly divisible it's simply a case of figuring whether to need to add or subtract coins to fill the bag correctly.

EDIT

NB: There is much that could be done to this to improve validation.  For some odd reason I must have copied an earlier draft of this that was missing an exit sub from ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged which I rectified, but that is by no means the only piece of validation that you should be considering.

Comment: Ok thats ms Dom I shall try the tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Never done dictionaries before so I'll be kean to see how they work. Thanks you

Comment: Thanks Dom I have used this and it works to check the bags weight. How could I add display the total number of coins that have been added or removed from all the coins that I have entered.

Comment: Let me just ensure that we are singing from the same hymn sheet.  In your original question you say that you are entering a weight, and a coin type. You are now suggesting in your comment that you are adding coins.  Are you really trying to say, 'how do I know (from the weight that I entered and the coin type that I selected, how many coins do I currently have and how many do I need to either add or subtract in order to have a bag that meets the requirements of the bank?'

Comment: Yes this it what I needed it to do. So if the person entered a weight that was not the what it should be for that particular coin the program would say how many coins to either add or remove to meet the correct weight. I get my program to do this, but I now need to have a running total of how many coins in total have been either added or removed from the weights enteterd. So if I have 5 bags entered and each had 2 coins to add it would say "in total you need to add 10 more coins". Thanks for your help with this I really appreciate it.